# Abstract factory pattern in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Mine is a reporting application where users can do group by/aggregation on the grid columns on the UI.
I have a configuration mode - client side and server side - based on the flag grouping/aggregation is done on the client side/server side.

I have 3 services which talk to each other to do this - and their behaviour is completely different based on the mode - as per my knowledge this fits for abstract factory pattern - creating family of objects(services in angular) based on a condition - How can i achieve this in angular?

Note: the user can not flip this mode on run time - it is determined only once when the user logs in.

Answer (score 0):

## Config factory injection

You could create a configuration factory that is holding the currently active mode and then inject the singleton of this factory into each factory to affect the behavior of your app.

Please have a look at the demo below or this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/wj03u2hz/1/).

## $injector for dynamically injecting factory

Another way is to dynamically inject the service depending on the selected mode. I would use this method because it's easier to read if you're having a complex app.

The important point here is `$injector.get('service/factoryname')` to get the service for your selected mode. You don't need to do it with a provider. The same will work with a factory for mode selection.

Please have a look at this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/axf5sp5e/5/).

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
  .controller('mainController', MainController)
  .run(function(config) {
    var mode = prompt('please enter mode');
    config.setMode(mode); // just for simulation config change --> later this in your auth.success promise
  })
  .factory('config', ConfigFactory)
  .factory('fact1', Factory1)
  .factory('fact2', Factory2);

function ConfigFactory() {
  var config = {
    mode: 0,
    setMode: setMode
  };

  return config;

  function setMode(mode) {
    this.mode = mode || 0;
  }
}

function Factory1(config) {
  console.log('config in factory1', config.mode);
  var mode = parseInt(config.mode);

  var factory1 = {
    method: function() {
      console.log('default method'); // e.g. for undefined mode
    },
    otherMethod: undefined,
  };

  var modeBehaviour = {
    0: {
      method: function() {
        console.log('something special for mode 0');
      },
      otherMethod: function() {
        console.log('only at mode 0 available')
      }
    },
    1: {
      method: function() {
        console.log('something special for mode 1');
      }
    }
  }

  angular.merge(factory1, modeBehaviour[mode]);

  return factory1;
}

function Factory2(config) {
  console.log('config in factory2', config.mode);
  var factory2 = {

  };

  return factory2;
}

function MainController(config, fact1, fact2) {
  this.mode = config.mode;
  console.log(fact1, fact2);

  fact1.method();

  if (typeof fact1.otherMethod === 'function') {
    fact1.otherMethod();
  }
  /*this.changeMode = function(mode) {
   config.setMode(mode);
  }*/
  //this.hello = 'hello from angular';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController as ctrl" ng-cloak>
  current mode: {{ctrl.mode}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks A wolf. Seems like we cannot have abstract factory pattern with Angular. But I am going to go with factory pattern for each service. Since I am using typescript it's easy and maintainable for me to use abstract classes and inheritance to design it better.